# Need script to run function over infinite rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to create an array formula to run a specific function over an infinite number of rows i.e. each time a new row is created in the google spreadsheet, the formula should run for that new line as well. However I have come the conclusion that I need script for this, and that an array function will not do the job.

My initial spreadsheet has a row on data and essentially what I need is the following: if colum BC="x" (starting on row 3) then find the largest value in the range of columns R:AI. I had tried the following as a formula:

=ArrayFormula(if(BC3:BC="x",MAX(R3:AI3),"")
)

However clearly this did not work and I can obviously see why - whilst the array does take into account all values in column BC starting with BC3, it will only ever return the max value from range R3:AI3.

I also tried:

=ArrayFormula(if(BC3:BC="x",MAX(R3:AI),"")
)

But this then returns the highest value for the entire range R3:AI, and again the same value in each row in column BC.

So I think an array formula is not suitable - could anybody help with a script to perform this function?

Answer (score 1):

You can still pull this off with an ArrayFormula you just have to make use of a few other functions, namely `ROW()` and `INDIRECT()`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(BC3:BC="x", MAX(INDIRECT("R" & ROW() & ":A" & ROW()))))
```

**EDIT**

Apparently the above approach won't work as certain formulas such as INDIRECT operate independently of the ARRAYFORMULA they are nested in. The closest I was able to get to a solution was this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(BC3:BC="x", "=MAXA(R"&ROW(BC3:BC)&":A"&ROW(BC3:BC)&")",""))
```

I wasn't able to get it to work but its as far as I got. It looks like you may need a script after all.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! I had read about these row and indirect functions somewhere but couldn't quite work out how they worked. However, I've now put the formula in as follows:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(BC3:BC="x", MAX(INDIRECT("R" & ROW() & ":AI" & ROW()))))

(note the range is from R:AI not A) and it produces the same result for the entire column BC. It generates always the result in row 3 which is the row the formula is entered in :/